# Use variable inside of WP_query

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to echo $zipcode_term inside of the 'tax_query' but it is not working...

```
wp_reset_query();
$zipcode_term = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'zipcode' );

$args = array(
'tax_query' => array(
    array(

        'taxonomy' => 'zipcode',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => '.$zipcode_term.'
    )
)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I have echoed $zipcode_term and it displays it correctly so I know that part is working, how can I express it inside of the array correctly?

Answer (score 0):

should `'terms' => '.$zipcode_term.'` have the apostrophe and concatenation around your variable?

```
'terms' => $zipcode_term
```

?